# How to make a button focus in a thread in C#

Tags: c#, focus, button

I need to make a button focus at the end of a thread.
The Button.Focus() method does not seem to work.

for exmaple:

```
Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Thread myThread = new Thread(theThread);
   myThread.Start();
}

theThread()
{
  ... 
  Button2.Focus(); // does not seem to focus the button
}
```

However, if I put Button2.Focus() in Button1_Click it will focus, but for my project I can't do that.

Answer (score 3):

For a generic solution to these kind of problems, take a look at [`SyncronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) class. For Windows forms, however, you could use the [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method and in WPF, you could use [`Dispatcher.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx):

```
//WinForms:
Invoke(delegate{ Button2.Focus(); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Any UI changes have to be made from the form's main thread.  Look into calling the form's "Invoke" method from your own thread.  You'll want to pass "Invoke" a delegate to a method that calls the "Focus" method on your button.